# Good approach to persist nullable value types in a database string column

Tags: c#, serialization, type-conversion

I'm wondering what’s the best way to persist an **nullable value type** in a **string** column in the DB?

#### Background:

My plan is to have a generic message table in the DB, containing the Resource Name, used by the Web to find the localized resource string, and the format items, serialized as a concatenated string:

```
TABLE LogMessages
(
  ResourceName NVARCHAR(50),
  FormatItems NTEXT
)
```

Lets say I have a resource file in the Web, containing a resource entry **"UserSetup"** with the value **"User {0} has been created on {1:d}."**.

As an example, an entry in the table might be:

ResourceName: **"UserSetup"** --> Referencing the resource's Name field
FormatItems : **"System.String;Bob|System.DateTime;2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000"**

The Web will then restore the array and pass it to the **string.Format(...)**  method.

#### Question:

Beside the question if this concept makes sense, **I wonder how a NULL value (e.g. int?) should be persisted in the concatenated string?**. Is there any keyword for null references I can use?

One idea was to use a keyword like NULL, e.g. "System.String;**NULL**|System.DateTime;2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000". But this might conflict with an object where the value is actually the string "NULL".

What would you recommend to persist a nullable type and the null value?

Appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Is there a difference in your logic between `null` and `string.Empty` (`""`)? For value types you could just use `string.Empty`, as in: `System.Int32;|System.DateTime;2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000`.

Comment: @Corak Thanks Corak. You're right, so easy but I haven't thought about it. I will threat string.Empty and null the same and use the string.Empty as the null identificator for other value types. I would mark your comment as the answer, but thats not possible for comments.

Comment: Please don't threat `string.Empty` and `null`. They get scared easily. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

How about trying using a null String: "" ?